# Haskell SimpleHTTP get response code

Tags: http, haskell, response, http-response-codes

I'm trying to get the response code (200,404 etc) from i THINK a Response type in the HTTP class with simpleHTTP
Thus far:

```
--how to get the http response Int from response
getStatusCode response  = print 0

--this works...
--- othercode ---
rsp <- simpleHTTP (defaultGETRequest_ clean_uri) 
file_buffer <- getResponseBody(rsp)
--this fails
response = (getStatusCode rsp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
getResponseCode :: Result (Response ty) -> IO ResponseCode
```

from the [`Network.HTTP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.2.5/doc/html/Network-HTTP.html) module if you're using HTTP-4000.2.4 or later. For earlier versions of [`HTTP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.2.5/doc/html/Network-HTTP.html), you would have to pattern-match yourself on the `rspCode` field apparently, similar to the way shown below for the `rspReason` field.

If you are interested in the reason, use the `rspReason` field of [`Response`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.2.5/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Base.html#t%3aResponse), after

```
rsp <- simpleHTTP ...
```

you have

```
rsp :: Either ConnError (Response ty)  -- Result is a type synonym for (Either ConnError)
```

and can access the reason per

```
let reason = case rsp of
               Left err -> show err  -- for example
               Right response -> rspReason response
putStrLn $ "Here's why: " ++ reason
```

Comment: kewl will try it, but that only gives me the signature ?

Comment: Yes, that gives you only a triple of `Int`s, for the reason, the `Response` type has a `rspReason` field.

Comment: getResponseCode :: Result (Response ty) -> IO ResponseCode

   The type signature for `getResponseCode'
      lacks an accompanying binding

Comment: You should use it as `responseCode <- getResponseCode rsp`. `getResponseCode` is defined in `Network.HTTP`.

Comment: Not in scope: `getResponseCode'
    Perhaps you meant `getResponseBody' (imported from Network.HTTP)

Comment: Which version of `HTTP` are you using?

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Haskell. erm How do i check it ? Can I check it via ghci ? import Network.HTTP (showVersion) <-- doesn work

Comment: You can check the version with `ghc-pkg list HTTP` from the command line. I just searched, and `getResponseCode` was only added in 4000.2.4, the second newest version. For older versions, you seem to need to pattern-match yourself.

Comment: HTTP-4000.2.2
 Ahh ja i'm trying to get that part right the pattern matching :)

Comment: Agg I'm giving up ! Copying that function from the new source. Now gives me Result not in scope :(

Comment: Does the example I gave for the reason in my (once again updated) answer help?

Comment: To be honest no, since i want to get the response code not the reason :( But thanks for you help !

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS :) THANKS WORKING and yes based on you reason example ! Althou I have no Idea how it works :(